# Rational maps in analytic topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a irreducible complex projective variety. Consider a rational map of complex projective varieties $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$, i.e. a morphism $U\longrightarrow Y$, where $U$ is a Zariski-open of $X$. In the analytic topology the morphism $U^{an}\longrightarrow Y^{an}$ is continuos and moreover, it's very well known that $U^{an}$ is dense in $X^{an}$, as $U$ is dense in $Y$.

My question is:

Is it possible extend the map $U^{an}\longrightarrow Y^{an}$ to a continuos map $X^{an}\longrightarrow Y^{an}$?

Comment: Consider $X=Y=\Bbb C$ with $U=\Bbb C^\times$ and $f: z\mapsto 1/z$. This example should be instructive.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about this!

Comment: ps: However my varieties are assumed to be projective :)

Comment: Pardon my misread. In that case, consider the resolution of singularities of a nodal cubic in $\Bbb P^2$. On the smooth locus, this is an isomorphism, so talking about a rational map from the nodal cubic to $\Bbb P^1$ makes sense, except that there is no choice of image for the node which makes this map into a continuous map as you request.